# BufferedReader.readLine doeasn't start from the file beginning and skips lines

Tags: java, eclipse

I need to read a text file line by line till I find a specific string. I'm using `BufferedReader.readLine()` but when I debug I find that it starts from the third line in the file and skips lines after that.
Here is my code:

```
try {
    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));

    String line1 = null;

    while ((line1 = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line1.toString() == invocation0) {
            found = true;
            return false;
        } else if (line1 == invocation1) {
            found = true;
            return true;
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (reader != null)
        try {
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
}
```

I would really appreciate any help, as I tried many different solutions for this and still can't solve this issue.

the content of the file is like:

.//============================================================================
.// File: abc.mark
.// Description: anything
.// Notice: anything
.// .//============================================================================
.invoke RemoveClass("Properties",0)

Comment: No, BufferedReader really *doesn't* do that. Please edit your post to include a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem (with decent indentation), a sample text file, expected output and actual output. I note that you're using `==` to check for string equality, which is likely to be the *real* problem. See http://tinyurl.com/so-java-string-equality

Comment: use .equals method instead of ==. Also you dont need toString() method in "line1.toString()" since line1 is alread a String.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(line1.equals(invocation0))
```

Use `equals()` method for `String` value comparison.

Also, instead of `return` within the `if`, you can use a `break`. This is just a suggestion though.

Comment: i would appreciate if you can help me with the big problem is that the value of line1 = reader.readLine() is not correct . it skips lines and start from the middle of the file.

Comment: because as @JonSkeet mentioned, `BufferedReader` won't skip lines on its own.

Comment: @MariamSherif - I just tried with the text you updated, and it read from the starting line only(**as it would, should & did**).

Comment: any suggestion about why i still have the problem in my environment

Comment: Do this:- `while ((line1 = reader.readLine()) != null) {
          System.out.println(line1);` and show the output the sysout is printing.

Answer (score 0):

BufferedReader should not be skipping the anything. Unfortunately you are the one who is making read method to skip the line. The equlaity operator `==` will not compare the content of any two strings, rather it compares whether they are of same object. You could possibly avoid it in two ways.

1. Call the intern() on invocation0 (line1 object should have been interned before anyway)
2. More precisely use equals method line1.equals(invocaton0)

This [link](http://blog.enrii.com/2006/03/15/java-string-equality-common-mistake/) may be of some help for you to understand it better.

Comment: i edited my code to be:

try {
     reader = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( path) );
    
     String line1 = null;
    
     while((line1 = reader.readLine()) != null){
      
       System.out.println(line1);
      
     
      
     }
     } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if( reader != null )
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
        }

and the printed lines are not like the file. it still skips lines !!

Comment: can you post your full code snippet including the what do you mean by invocation ?

Comment: forget about invocation, i'm now just trying to read the file line by line and print each line on console, like i mentioned in previous  comment